# media print image width and height not reflecting

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code that positions the image correctly to the page preview when part of the webpage is to be printed

```
<style media="print">

  #cropped_image{
     padding-top: 70px;
      padding-left: 6px;
      display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 200%;
    width: 200%;

 }
</style>
```

however the width and height property doesnt seem to reflect on the preview? any turnaround for this?

Comment: Are you closing your style block? i.e. </style>

Comment: i forgot to include in the post but in my original code it is closed.

Comment: the preview seems to follow whatever the size of the image is not from what is declared in media print

Answer (score 0):

please clarify me if im wrong is you code like this :
1.)  or 
2.)

```css
.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #222;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

 #cropped_image{
     padding-top: 70px;
      padding-left: 6px;
      display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;

 }
 @media print{
    #cropped_image{
     padding-top: 70px;
      padding-left: 6px;
      display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    border:1px solid red

 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

<img src="red.png" id="cropped_image"/>
</div>
```